# ASP.NET: User control with dependent attributes

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, attributes

I'm writing a user control with two attributes, `A` and `B`.  I want the programmer using this control to be warned when defining a value for attribute `A` but not for `B`.

Can I accomplish this somehow?

Comment: Warned at compile time, or at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just throw an ArgumentException at runtime in the User Control's Page_Load() method.